# click event for elements loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am making image slider . i am loading all images using ajax .i want to write click event for the images but because they are loaded with ajax they are not working .

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "photos.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                        var path = $(this).attr('path');
                        var width = $(this).attr('width');
                        var height = $(this).attr('height');
                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
                        var longdesc = $(this).find('longdesc').text();
                        var description = $(this).find('desc').text();
                        $('#myImageFlow').prepend('<img src="'+path+'" id='+id+'  height="'+height+'"  width="'+ width+'" longdesc="'+longdesc+'" alt="'+alt+'"/>');
                        imgArr[i] = description;
                        i = i+1;

                    });
                }
            }).done(function() {





      /* ===================================== */
      //$("#myImageFlow").show();

      // $("#myImageFlow img").photoSwipe({ enableMouseWheel: false , enableKeyboard: false });


                        $('img:lt(3)').addClass('t1');
                        $('img:gt(3)').addClass('t2');



                    });

      $.getScript('js/iSlider.js');
      $.getScript('js/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.js');


 });


 $('img').click( function() {

    alert("image clicked");     
   }
```

i tried using ,

```
$('img').live('load', function() {
```

but it is not working . i want to aplly some css method each time image is clicked.
click event is working fine without Ajax function .

Comment: add event binding code to your ajax success event!

Answer (score 4):

You may use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like this:

```
$('body').on('click','img',function(){
    //do something..
});
```

You may bind it also on a container that is closer to `img`'s like `div`.
And `.live()` is already deprecated in latest versions of JQuery.

Comment: Can you give some reference about your statement that `.live()` is already dead..

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/ Here's a reference stating that it is already deprecated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'img', function() {
  alert('image clicked');
}
```

Assuming you're using an older version of jQuery which does have `.live`,

```
$('img').live('load', function() {
```

doesn't work because you need to bind to `click`, not `load`.

This would work:

```
$('img').live('click', function() {
```

but you should use `.on` as `.live` was removed in recent version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myImageFlow').on("click", 'img',  function() {

    alert("image clicked");     
   });
```